# When you don't specify an order- why does result order vary?

Tags: python, computer-science

I am in the *very* early stages of learning Python. This question has more to do with basic understanding than coding- hopefully I tag it correctly. I am reading my coursework and it says

> "Run the program below that displays the ... The indentation and
>   spacing of the... key-value pairs simply provides more readability.
>   **Note that order is not maintained in the dict when printed."**

I know I can specify so that the order is the same each time. I can do that. I want to know when you write a program and run it why do the results get returned in a different order when not specified? Is it because of the way it gets handled in the processor?

Thanks.

Comment: Please update your question with some code which demonstrates the orders you are referring to.

Comment: Your question is about how dictionaries are ordered. In the past (pre python 3.6) dictionary order was NOT preserved. The interpreter was free to re-organize the dictionary however it felt was best (by ordering the hashes, I think). However in python 3.6+, **dictionary order is preserved based on insertion**

Comment: Prior to python 3.7, python dictionaries were not guaranteed to be ordered. This is just a feature of how dictionaries were implemented, the details are quite technical. There are other data structures that preserve order, such as `list`, `tuple` and `OrderedDict`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer has nothing to do with Python, and everything to do with data structures - this behavior is universal and expected across all languages that implement a similar data structure. In Python it's called a dictionary, in other languages it's called a Map or a Hash Map or a Hash Table. There are a few other similar names for the same underlying data structure.

The Python dictionary is an **Associative** collection, as opposed to a Python List (which is just an Array), where its elements are contiguous in memory.

The big advantage that dictionaries (associative collections) offer is fast and constant look up times (O(1)) - arrays also offer fast look up since calculating an index is trivial - however a dictionary consists of key-value pairs where the key can be anything as long as it is hashable.

Essentially, to determine the "index" where an associated value should go in an associative container, you take the key, hash it, devise some way of mapping the hash to a number and treat that number like an index. As unlikely as it is for two different objects to yield the same hash, it could theoretically happen - what's more likely to happen is that your [hash-to-number procedure maps two unique hashes to the same number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) - in any case, collisions like this can happen, and there are [strategies for handling these collisions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Collision_resolution).

The point is, the hash of a key determines the order in which the associated value appears in the collection - therefore, **there is no inherent order**.

Comment: Starting with 3.7 dictionaries preserve insertion order
https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping

Comment: Yes, that is correct. However, the OP obviously isn't using Python 3.7.